# Export node report base on Word and Excel template

Tags: nodes, importing-exporting

I want to export node content to Word or Excel.
Are there any module to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Views Data Export](http://drupal.org/project/views_data_export/) to export in many popular table formats.  XLS, CSV, DOC, TXT and XML.

Some other modules worth mentioning here:

[Views Datasource](http://drupal.org/project/views_datasource)

[Service Views](http://drupal.org/project/services_views)

It should go without saying that the modules above will require Views be installed and enabled.

Answer (score 1):

1. For exporting the node to excel sheet you can use the [Sheetnode](http://drupal.org/project/sheetnode) module. It also has other options of import and export (e.g. import from Microsoft excel .xls and .xlsx; also from OpenOffice.org calc .ods files; also the sheets from Google Docs.
2. For exporting to word you can use the [Node to Word](http://drupal.org/project/node_to_word) module. Currently it is for version 6.x. But, a working copy of the module for Drupal 7 can be downloaded from the [thread running for D7 port](http://drupal.org/node/1462686).

Answer (score 0):

For excel you can use [feeds](https://drupal.org/project/feeds) module too. It has many advance configurations for import and export.