# Export node to Ms Word file

Tags: 7, importing-exporting

I would need to export nodes in Ms Word format.

I would need to mantain the node structure or to apply a template.

I don't want to export data in a table like "Views data export" module does.

In Drupal 6 it was done using "node to word" module (https://drupal.org/project/node_to_word), but the module doesn't exist for Drupal 7.

thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

The module [Views data export](https://drupal.org/project/views_data_export) claims to do it:

> Style plugins are included that support exporting in the following
>   types:
>
> ```
> CSV
> Microsoft XLS
> Microsoft DOC
> Basic TXT
> XML.
> ```

So you should be able to construct a view of fields or rendered entities and select the display for a doc file.

See a similar question here: [Export node report base on Word and Excel template](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36383/export-node-report-base-on-word-and-excel-template)

Comment: Actually views_data_export does NOT support Doc format.  It's only "planned" according to the git page.  And the project is stale, so it likely never will support doc.

Answer (score 1):

In stead of including all fields used in the content type you want to export to Doc with Views Data Export you gotta choose the 'Rendered Content' field, set display to 'show complete entity' and view mode to 'full content'.

That way the entire node gets rendered into one column of the table:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
    <thead><tr><th>Rendered Content</th></tr></thead>    <tbody>      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is the closest I got to achieve this, but then I'm unable to exclude or customize fields.